# Get values from the service class to the activity

Tags: android

I have TrackingService component to track the location of the buses in my city based on Crowdsourcing. In the TrackingService class I have variable `pLong, pLat` to stored the latitude and longitude when they are calaculated in the `onLocatiochChanged()`. The TrackingService is operating in the background, where the data is transmitted to the server.
I have an Map Activity to display the location of the buses, the user selected in the MainActivity( as Filter).

Everything is working great but when I try to display the user's current location in the map activity  the received `double lng = ts.pLong;double lat = ts.pLat;` in the `displayMyLocation()` are `0.0` although they have values when I dubbuged them and the values are being sent to the server but when I invoke them in the `displayMyLocation()` they are `0.0`

I cant start the map activity from the `onLocationChanged()` by passing an intent to the map activity.

How can I get these values in my Map activity?

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    public double pLong;
    public double pLat;
    ...
        @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            pLong = location.getLongitude();
            pLat = location.getLatitude();
           .....

     }  

}
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
  .....
    private void displayMyLocation() {

        TrackingService ts = new TrackingService();
         double lng = ts.pLong;
         double lat = ts.pLat;       
         LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat,lng);
         MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title("My Location")
                    .position(ll);
         myLocatMarker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);

    }
  ...

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you create the TrackService object, does not mean that the service is started.

You need to start it via context's

```
startService(<Intent>);
```

When it gets the GPS info is when it will update, which can take a little time.

What you should do is in your service, you should pass the Activity instance or a callback to the service so it can notify the Activity when it has new info and you can update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

is your service(TrackingService) bounded to your activity ?

Comment: The TrackingService is being started from the MainActivity when the app launches.